# python strings strip characters

Tags: python, string

How can I strip away only the characters`devices/` from a string `devices/slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/23`?

If I try:

```
device = 'devices/slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/23'
device = device.strip('devices/')

print(device)
```

why does this print as lop off the `s` in `slipstream_internal` that I want? This prints:

```
'lipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/23'
```

I am using Python 3.8

Comment: `device.replace("devices/","")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strip('devices/')` will remove any of the characters that you pass as an argument from the beginning and end of a string. Think of the argument as a set of characters to remove, not as a substring or sequence to remove.

If you just want to remove `'devices/'` from the beginning of the string, try using

```
device.replace('devices/', '')
```

or even better

```
device.replace('devices/', '', 1)
```

to make sure only the first occurrence is removed.

Answer (score 4):

#### Problem

The `str.strip` method remove, from beginning, any char that is contained in the the given parameter, no matter the order, until one isn't in the given values, so these calls are identical

```
device.strip('devices/')
device.strip('/devices')
device.strip('/cdsiev')
```

It contains an `s`, so the `s` is removed

---

#### Solution

- use `re.sub` with `'^devices/'` (the `^` in pattern ensures it removes only frmo beginning)

  ```
  import re
  device = 'devices/slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/23'
  device = re.sub('^devices/', '', device)
  ```
- `str.replace` with count of 1, but can remove not beginning value

  ```
  device = device.replace('devices/', '', 1)
  ```
- Or `str.removeprefix` from `python3.9`

  ```
  device = device.removeprefix('devices/')
  ```

Comment: Why `re`? You can just use `str.replace` instead of importing external libraries

Comment: @not_speshal `re` isn't an external library, it's a module in the standard library.

Comment: My bad - but still isn't needed I think?

Comment: @azro I added the missing `^` anchor into your regexp. :)

Comment: @not_speshal You can't replace a string exactly at the start of a string in a single operation without a regexp (or Python 3.9's `removeprefix`).

Comment: @AKX - This works: `'devices/slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/23'.replace('devices/','',1)`

Comment: @not_speshal it only works if you're *sure* the string starts with that substring.  And don't forget to assign the result back, Python doesn't do in-place updates on strings.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a string replace function.

```
device = 'devices/slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/23'
device = device.replace('devices/', '')

print(device)
```

Comment: This would remove _any_ `devices/`, e.g. `devices/foo/devices/bar` would become `foo/bar`.

Comment: You can limit the number of replaces with `"devices/foo/devices/bar".replace("devices/", "", 1)`

Comment: @not_speshal it would still do the wrong thing with `dev/foo/devices/bar`.